# Using REST Services acquiring limited data from DataBase like LayerDefinition

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arcgis-rest-api

I am working with ArcGIS Server 10.2 and MS SQL DB.
I have a requirement in which i need to retrieve limited data using a query from a bulk data using the same Map Service REST URL which can give me filtered Spatial Data while interacting from server to DB. This filtered spatial data will be added to the Map.

**Scenario:** I have 17 Town data which when added to the map makes the map loading and rendering slow in hosted application. If i need only 4 town data then i should be able to get only data of the same from database using Map Service REST URL without change in URL.

**My Understanding**:I have some understanding where the REST API can help me in creating a temporary Table in Server side which will collect newly filtered data. This table can be accessed with the same URL but the destination of the table will be changed.

Comment: What is your question?